# Extra worksheets in C# Excel app

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing an Excel app in C# which does some data visualization. The first stage of the analysis is to copy the data from a single sheet in an input workbook to a new sheet in an output workbook where the analysis is performed.

This runs correctly on my laptop but when the client I am producing the code for runs the same application, they get some extra worksheets created which cause the code to crash.

It's pretty difficult to debug the application on the client's PC so I am having difficultly understanding how it's possible the results are different on two different machines.

Setup code is below, any help at all would be incredibly useful. Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 14.

```
Excel.Workbooks wbs = excelApp.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook dataSource = wbs.Open(inFile);

//get the data sheet from the source file
Excel.Sheets dataSourceSheets = dataSource.Worksheets;
Excel.Worksheet dataSourceSheet =  (Excel.Worksheet)dataSourceSheets.get_Item(1);

//create a new workbook
dataOutput = wbs.Add();
outputSheets = dataOutput.Worksheets;

//ensure there are only 2 sheets in the output
int osc = outputSheets.Count;
for (int i = 2; i < osc; ++i)
{
        outputSheets.get_Item(i).Delete();
}

//setup summary and contents pages
summaryPage = outputSheets.get_Item(1);
summaryPage.Name = "Summary";
contentsPage = outputSheets.Add(Type.Missing, summaryPage);
contentsPage.Name = "Contents";

dataSourceSheet.Copy(Type.Missing, contentsPage); //copy the sheet AFTER contents page
dataSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)outputSheets.get_Item(outputSheets.Count);
dataSheet.Name = "Raw Data";

//fails with outputSheets.Count == 5
if (outputSheets.Count != 3)
{
        throw new Exception("Error, there are too many sheets here!");
}
```

Comment: Do you and the user have the same versions of Excel?

Comment: A possibility to consider: The client's Excel defaults to a different number of Excel worksheets than your own. You can test this on your own machine by opening Excel, click FILE - OPTIONS. In the GENERAL tab, change `INCLUDE THIS MANY SHEETS` to a new number and see if that impacts your program

Comment: Perhaps `osc` needs to be recalculated?

Comment: Great, thank you! Problem solved. @user3561813 Is there any way to set all the 'configuration' values of excel to match mine (e.g. via a presupplied config file) in case of other configuration differences?

Comment: @Max To be honest, I'm not sure of the best way to go about doing so. Perhaps posting a follow up question to the board will provide greater assistance. Sorry I couldn't be more help.